# Why Does Excel VBA Range.Find Return Incorrect Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a single Sub in VBA that is looking at a key column in the worksheet and pulling in a value from a text file based on the value in column. Column A has a series of 3 digit numbers from 110 to 717, 80 values in all. I set a Range to ("A:A"), then search that with Range.find for the key value in the text file. The first cell in the range is A1, with a value of 110. Range.Find returns A6 for this value. I'm not sure what could be happening in the space of one or two lines of code that could cause this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my sub. This is the entirety of my code.

```
Sub DoTheWork()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FSO As Object
Dim TF As Object
Dim TextFile
Dim TextLine
Dim TextLines As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim Code As String
Dim PurposeCode As Range
Dim SearchArea As Range
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
Dim KeyRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
TextFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TF = FSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile, 1)
TextLine = TF.ReadAll
TF.Close
TextLines = Split(TextLine, vbCrLf)
Set PurposeCode = ws.Range("A:A")
For x = 0 To UBound(TextLines, 1)
    Code = Right(Left(TextLines(x), 4), 3)
    If IsNumeric(Code) Then
        Code = CInt(Code)
        Set SearchArea = PurposeCode.Find(Code, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext)
        If Not SearchArea Is Nothing Then
            KeyRow = SearchArea.Row
            Cells(KeyRow, 2).Value = Code
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Sample output:
[image: Worksheet after Macro finishes]

Thanks

**Edit to show contents of TextFile:**

```
 110     17     0.25
 111      1     0.01
 113      5     0.06
 115      3     0.03
 120    582     8.77
 121                
 140   3,053   45.02
```

So I am opening the text file, reading all the lines into an array, then taking the three digit number in the first 4 characters of the file and matching it against the same three digit code in the spreadsheet on sheet2. I'm only working with sheet2, so I specified sheet2 when I set ws.

I did change to `ws.Cells(KeyRow, 2).Value = Code` and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I do not get that output, I get the correct output.

Comment: Your search code is looking at the second sheet, but your results are being placed on a different sheet where the list (or some other list) is in a different position...  It's always a good idea to never use Cells/Range without a qualifying worksheet object.  E.g you should use `ws.Cells(KeyRow, 2).Value = Code`

Comment: ...at least that is my best guess at the problem...

Comment: I discovered that when I specify `ws = wb.Worksheets("2018")`  instead of `Sheets(2)` or `Worksheets(2)`, then the search works correctly. This is isn't extremely useful as this means someone will need to maintain this sheet and update as the years progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, specifically creating a function to return sheet names as alluded to in my comment, I discovered that there are a number of hidden sheets on this workbook, with sheet2 being a sheet from 2004 with the same numbers but with 5 header rows first that were causing my search results to be offset by 5.